# Associate Array Sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array like below. I need to sort array by most tags matched.

```
[0] =>[ 
     [id]=>1,
     [tags]=>Apple,Banana,Mango
    ],
[1] =>[ 
     [id]=>2,
     [tags]=>Apple,Mango,Banana,Orange
    ],
[2] =>[ 
     [id]=>3,
     [tags]=>Mango,Orange
    ],,
[3] =>[ 
     [id]=>4,
     [tags]=>Blackberry,Orange
    ],
[4] =>[ 
     [id]=>5,
     [tags]=>Orange,Blackberry,Banana
    ]
```

I have string of tags to sort array.

```
$tags_str = "Mango,Banana,Orange".  // dynamic string (no. of tags not fix)
```

Array should be sort in desc order of tags matched.

Expected output:

```
[0] =>[ 
      [id]=>2,
      [tags]=>Apple,Mango,Banana,Orange   // 3 tags matched
     ],
[1] =>[ 
     [id]=>1,
     [tags]=>Apple,Banana,Mango          // 2 tags matched
    ],
[2] =>[ 
     [id]=>3,
     [tags]=>Mango,Orange                // 2 tags matched
    ],
[3] =>[ 
     [id]=>5,
     [tags]=>Orange,Blackberry,Banana   // 2 tags matched
    ],
[4] =>[ 
     [id]=>4,
     [tags]=>Blackberry,Orange          // 1 tag matched
    ]
```

How can achieve this in php ?

Comment: Are you just asking us to do your work for you? If you've had a problem with something you've tried you can ask that, otherwise you'll probably not get reliable help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP don't deserve it but, on possible solution

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$toSort = [
     ['id'=>1,'tags'=>'Apple,Banana,Mango']
    ,['id'=>2,'tags'=>'Apple,Mango,Banana,Orange']
    ,['id'=>3,'tags'=>'Mango,Orange']
    ,['id'=>4,'tags'=>'Blackberry,Orange']
    ,['id'=>5,'tags'=>'Orange,Blackberry,Banana']

];

$tags_str = "Mango,Banana,Orange";

$tagSearch = explode(',',$tags_str);
foreach ($toSort as &$v) {
    $v['m'] = count(array_intersect($tagSearch,explode(',',$v['tags'])));
}

uasort($toSort,function ($a,$b){
    return $b['m']-$a['m'];
});

print_r($toSort);
```